# How to make ordered select in the cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( 
    uid uuid,
    rec int,
    Primary key (uid, rec)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (rec DESC ) ;
```

I want to get records starting from some uid and limit 100, but cassandra doesn't allow to make request like this:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE uid > ee0f57b0-255c-11e5-9f08-8f9ef2abcffc LIMIT 100
```

And request :

```
SELECT * FROM test
```

outputs all records random ordered.

Comment: See wether this helps select * from test where TOKEN(uid) > TOKEN(ee0f57b0-255c-11e5-9f08-8f9ef2abcffc) limit 100;

Comment: It makes paging , but doesn't make ordering.INSERT INTO test (uid, rec ) VALUES ( ee0f57b0-255c-11e5-9f08-8f9ef2abcdef, 1);
INSERT INTO test (uid, rec ) VALUES ( ee0f57b0-255c-11e5-9f08-8f9ef2abcdcc, 2);
INSERT INTO test (uid, rec ) VALUES ( ee0f57b0-255c-11e5-9f08-8f9ef2abcffc, 3);

SELECT * FROM test where TOKEN(uid) > TOKEN(ee0f57b0-255c-11e5-9f08-8f9ef2abcdef) limit 100; 
outputs 0 rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do a range query in CQL, you need to have the records in the same partition.  So if you want to do a range query on uid, it would need to be a clustering column instead of a partition key.  And data is sorted by clustering columns, not by partition keys.

But it doesn't make a lot of sense to do a range query on a uuid since they are usually considered random numbers and not ordered.  If you used timeuuid then they would be ordered by creation time.

If you are trying to read ranges of uuid's so that you can process the data in chunks, then you would make uuid a clustering column and have a partition key for the chunk number.

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra does not allow range queries on partition keys.  As Jim stated, you'll need to create a table with a different partition key, and apply your range to a clustering column.

> outputs all records random ordered.

Incorrect.  While results returned from a CQL `SELECT` without a `WHERE` clause may appear to be randomly-ordered, they are being returned to you in the order that they are read from the disk.  You can see this when using the `token` function:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> SELECT uid, token(uid), rec FROM testrangeordering ;

 uid                                  | system.token(uid)    | rec
--------------------------------------+----------------------+-----
 559f31f1-04a5-4a65-959e-866b19f671e8 | -4639349469716736139 |   4
 559f31f1-04a5-4a65-959e-866b19f671e8 | -4639349469716736139 |   3
 559f31f1-04a5-4a65-959e-866b19f671e8 | -4639349469716736139 |   2
 559f31f1-04a5-4a65-959e-866b19f671e8 | -4639349469716736139 |   1
 c9cbd305-649f-4f6f-9c8a-1ebc4192def4 | -1664662098145733545 |   4
 c9cbd305-649f-4f6f-9c8a-1ebc4192def4 | -1664662098145733545 |   3
 c9cbd305-649f-4f6f-9c8a-1ebc4192def4 | -1664662098145733545 |   2
 c9cbd305-649f-4f6f-9c8a-1ebc4192def4 | -1664662098145733545 |   1
 4c0b5615-3782-411c-9791-7c2dfae4533c | -1466462644843772696 |   1

(9 rows)
```

As you can see, your results are in order by the hashed token value of their partition key (`uid`), and your designated ordering is reflected *within* each partition.

And to echo what Jim said (again) range querying makes more sense to do with a timeuuid.  To fix your partition key issue, you may want to consider using a "bucket."  Let's say that I recreate your table with a timeuuid as the first clustering key, and a time bucket of the current year as the partition key:

```
CREATE TABLE testRangeOrderingByTime ( 
    bucket text,
    time timeuuid,
    rec int,
    Primary key (bucket, time, rec)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC, rec DESC) ;
```

Now I can run your range query (above) with a slight modification (restricting `bucket` to '2015' in my `WHERE` clause):

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> SELECT dateof(time), time, rec 
    FROm testrangeorderingbytime WHERE bucket='2015'
    AND time > ee0f57b0-255c-11e5-9f08-8f9ef2abcffc;

 system.dateof(time)      | time                                 | rec
--------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----
 2015-08-03 11:08:16-0500 | d9c51540-39f9-11e5-93d6-21b264d4c94d |   3
 2015-08-03 11:08:16-0500 | d9c403d0-39f9-11e5-93d6-21b264d4c94d |   3
 2015-08-03 11:08:16-0500 | d9c31970-39f9-11e5-93d6-21b264d4c94d |   3
 2015-08-03 11:07:43-0500 | c608e5e0-39f9-11e5-93d6-21b264d4c94d |   2
 2015-08-03 11:07:43-0500 | c6078650-39f9-11e5-93d6-21b264d4c94d |   2
 2015-08-03 11:07:43-0500 | c603dcd0-39f9-11e5-93d6-21b264d4c94d |   2
 2015-08-03 11:07:16-0500 | b5c95a20-39f9-11e5-93d6-21b264d4c94d |   1
 2015-08-03 11:07:16-0500 | b5c821a0-39f9-11e5-93d6-21b264d4c94d |   1
 2015-08-03 11:07:16-0500 | b5c625d0-39f9-11e5-93d6-21b264d4c94d |   1

(9 rows)
```

For further reference, I wrote an article discussing this topic on [PlanetCassandra](http://www.planetcassandra.org) last year ([We Shall Have Order!](http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/we-shall-have-order/)), which might help you.  Also, Patrick McFadin's article on [Getting Started With Time Series Data Modeling](http://academy.datastax.com/demos/getting-started-time-series-data-modeling) is a good read for this topic, as well.